# Get Facebook Photo of a Album with oauth2.0

Tags: facebook, image

Hello I have a script working well with the previous release of facebook API. 
With oauth 2.0 is not more working.
I solved the first problem of login, now I’m getting the list of  Album of Me but I cannot have the pictures.

This first script make the authorization and retrieve the album list.
When I select an album I pass the id and token to a php file that is in the second script. There I should load the picture of the specifyied album, but is not working.

I wonder if the problem is in the cover call `https://graph.facebook.com/'+album+'/picture?access_token='+access_token+`

And in the

```
FB.api("/"+albumid+"/photos",function(response){…
```

call..

Saomeone can help me to finde where I’m wrong?

Here is it possible to finde the complete script. [goo.gl/HY59u](http://goo.gl/HY59u)
Thanks

Federico

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    var loggedIn = false;
    var isLoaded = false;
    function loginFacebook() {
        if(!isLoaded) {
            alert("SDK is not yet loaded or something went wrong!");
            return false;
        }
        //initializes the facebook API
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "In attesa del permesso Facebook";
        //opens the Facebook login window for user
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {    
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Logged In. Ora puoi caricare gli album.";
                loggedIn = true;
                //disables the login button after the user has loggedIn
                document.getElementById("loginBtn").disabled = "Disabilitato";
                document.getElementById("loginBtn").style.display = "None";
                document.getElementById("albumBtn").style.display = "inline";
                document.getElementById("fb_logo").style.display = "None";
                document.getElementById("label_fb").style.display = "None";


            } else {
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Non hai effettuato il Facebook Login";
                loggedIn = false;
            }
        },{scope:'user_photos'});
    }
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxx', // App ID
      channelUrl : 'www.xxxxx.com/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    // Additional initialization code here
    isLoaded = true;
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));


//loads the all the album currently present in user's facebook profile

//Requests to '/me/albums'

function loadAlbums() {

      if(loggedIn) {

          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Caricando gli album dal tuo profilo Facebook";

          var counter = 0;

          FB.api('/me/albums', function(response) {

            document.getElementById("albumsList").innerHTML = '';

            for(var c in response["data"]) {

                addOption(response["data"][c].name,response["data"][c].id);

                counter++;

            }



            document.getElementById("albumBtn").style.display = "none";

            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "<p>Ci sono "+ counter +" album sul tuo profilo Facebook.</p><p> Scegli quello che vuoi inserire</p>";

          });

    } else {

        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Non hai effettuato il Facebook Login. Fai il Facebook login per caricare gli album.";

    }

}



//Adds a new album link into albumsList div

function addOption(opText,opVal) {

    document.getElementById("albumsList").style.display = "block";

    var v = document.getElementById("albumsList");

    v.innerHTML += '<br/><a target="_self" href="../facebook/album.php?id='+opVal+'&name='+opText+'">'+opText+'</a>';

}



function init() {

    var v = document.getElementById("loginBtn");

    v.onclick = loginFacebook;

    v.disabled = "";



    var v1 = document.getElementById("albumBtn");

    v1.onclick = loadAlbums;

    v1.disabled = "";

}



//calls init function once all the resources are loaded

window.addEventListener("load",init,true);
```

other script

```
<!-- Include the Facebook Javascript API -->

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<!-- Include the normal stylesheet-->

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var album = "";

    var access_token = "";

    function init() {

    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxx', // App ID
      channelUrl : 'www.sssss.com/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

        var _album = getParameter('id');

        if(_album!="") {

            album = _album;

            access_token = getAccessToken();



            document.getElementById("album_desc").innerHTML = unescape(getParameter('name'));



            //Album Header Photo link, https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/picture?access_token = ACCESS_TOKEN

            document.getElementById("album_cover").innerHTML += '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'+album+'/picture?access_token='+access_token+'" />';

            getAlbumPhotos(album);



        } else {

            album = "No Album ID passed";

            document.getElementById("album_cover").innerHTML = '<span class="error">'+album+'</span>';

        }

    }



    //queries the cookie on browser, to get the access_token

    function getAccessToken() {

        splitArray = document.cookie.split(";");

        access_token = "";

        for(var v in splitArray) {

            if(splitArray[v].substr(0,4)==" fbs") {

                access_token = splitArray[v];

                break;

            }

        }

        var arr = access_token.split("&")[0].split("=");

        return arr[arr.length-1];

    }



    //gets all the photos in the album

    function getAlbumPhotos(albumid) {

        //Queries /ALBUM_ID/photos

        FB.api("/"+albumid+"/photos",function(response){


            var photos = response["data"];

            document.getElementById("photos_header").innerHTML = "Foto("+photos.length+")";

            for(var v=0;v<photos.length;v++) {

                var image_arr = photos[v]["images"];



                var subImages_text1 = "("+(v+1)+")";



                //this is for the small picture that comes in the second column

                var subImages_text2 = '<img src="'+image_arr[(image_arr.length-1)]["source"]+'" class="imagedropshadow" />';



                //this is for the third column, which holds the links other size versions of a picture

                var subImages_text3 = "";



                //gets all the different sizes available for a given image

                for(var j = 0 ;j<image_arr.length;j++) {

                var Maxsize = Math.max(image_arr[0]["width"]);



                if(image_arr[j]["width"]== Maxsize)

                {

                    subImages_text3 += '<a target="_blank" href="'+image_arr[j]["source"]+'">Seleziona</a>  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_fb[]" value="'+image_arr[j]["source"]+'"> <input type="hidden" name="w_prev" id="w_prev" value="'+image_arr[(image_arr.length-1)]["width"]+'"/> <input type="hidden" name="h_prev" id="h_prev" value="'+image_arr[(image_arr.length-1)]["height"]+'"/> <br/>';

                }

                }

                addNewRow(subImages_text1,subImages_text2,subImages_text3);

            }

        });

    }



    function addNewRow(data1,data2,data3) {

        //inserts a new row into the table

        var table = document.getElementById("album_photos");

        var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

        var cell = row.insertCell(0);

        cell.innerHTML = data1;

        cell = row.insertCell(1);

        cell.innerHTML = data2;

        cell = row.insertCell(2);

        cell.innerHTML = data3;

    }



    //This function gets the value of album, passed in the request string

    function getParameter(name)

    {

        name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");

        //the regular expression that separates the album from the queryString

        var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";

        var regex = new RegExp( regexS );

        var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );

        if( results == null )

          return "";

        else

          return results[1];

    }



//calls init function once all the resources are loaded

window.addEventListener("load",init,true);

</script>
```